# Error in resuming ubuntu related to pciehp_resume

Tags: 14.04, wireless, suspend, resume

I sometimes(not always) cannot resume my laptop after suspending.
The following error is printed in the screen:

> pciehp 0000:00:1c.1:pcie04: Device 0000:03:00.0 already exists at 0000:03:00, cannot hot-add 
>   pciehp 0000:00:1c.1:pcie04: Cannot add device at 0000:03:00

Someobody mentioned this issue  [Here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1744725) but I haven't been able to find a solution:
"Currently, pciehp_resume will call pciehp_enable_slot() to add 
device if there is a device in the slot. But if the device was 
present before suspend, it's no necessary to add again. Now in 
such case, there is some uncomfortable message like above"

As far as I know, that device is Wireless card. While it is suspended, I didn't add/remove any cards. The only reason I could think of is that: the suspend phase didn't remove the Wireless card (but it is supposed to remove that card), so later on the resume phase would try to add this card, printing that uncomfortable message, not letting me to resume.

Is there a good solution for user like me? Or I should wait until someone fixes it in the kernel code?

Comment: Let's find out if it is the wireless card or some other. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 03:00 -A2` Edit your question to add the result.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on 16.04 & what fixed it was removing `acpid`:

```
sudo apt remove acpid
```

<s>I don't really know the consequences of this but now the laptop suspends & that might be more important than many things.</s>

This will remove [this package](https://wiki.debian.org/acpid), which controls pressing the power button.
But don't worry, works fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient bug with Nvidia cards drivers, probably related to the [acpid](https://wiki.debian.org/acpid) package

If you need to use your graphics card, switch the driver in *Sowtware&Updates > Additional Drivers* to the Nvidia driver and reboot. Don't forget that you still can't suspend your laptop.

Otherwise, just run `sudo apt remove acpid`, the driver will be switched to *xorg* automatically (*xorg* works fine). I didn't experience problems without *acpid* yet.

This is not a complete solution to the problem (I'm not sure if there exists one yet), but the only one way to use your graphics card.